# A simple approach of validating user input in PHP

Tags: php, validation, security, xss, sql-injection

I'm pretty new to PHP & SQL security and I was thinking about a solution for validating / filtering user input.

As far as I understand you have to mainly worry about 2 things:
**(1)** somebody injecting SQL queries into input fields that interact with a database
**(2)** somebody putting stuff like `<script>` tags inside their input which is then printed to the page again

While researching I found the following solutions:
**For (1):** prepared statements
**For (2):** validating / filtering HTML-tags

I know that you have to validate / filter any user input and as far as I understand most security leaks exist because of mistakes doing so.
For example simply filtering out the `<script>` tag in the following input:

```
email@<sc<script>ript>example.com
```

So what about a really simple algorithm rejecting any user input containing "<" or ">" (assuming there is no reason for users to use those symbols) and to replace something like `[b]` inside user input with `<b>` to allow specific tags? Isn't this a bulletproof approach to prevent malicious HTML content or what do I miss?

Also I'd like to know if using prepared statements all the time makes SQL injection impossible or is it still possible to do SQL injection on pages that exclusively use prepared statements?

Comment: 1: PDO, 2: htmlspecialchars

Comment: PDO driver to save data, strip_tags Function to senitize, and set head charset is UTF-8.

Comment: Regarding SQL injections, use parameterized prepared statements. There's no need to filter out anything really (security wise). Just save the data "as is". Then when you _output_ the data, you need to run it through `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` to protect yourself against XSS. It's better to sanitize the data when you output it since different use cases requires different sanitation. Validation should ofc always be done, but that's to check that the data is correct, checking that the data sent is in the correct format etc. and has nothing to do with sanitation or security.

Comment: ...and you shouldn't try and come up with your own type of sanitation (like removing `<` and `>`.) Hackers have many tricks up their sleeves to bypass "unsophisticated" sanitation (you basically need to know all the possible attack vectors to be able to rely on your own solution.) Use the built in functions in PHP instead, they have been tried and tested by millions for years.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, yes. But then you might be open to another attack. And you could fix that, but then you might still...

Because of that it's easier to whitelist. There are only certain characters allowed (though a more broad charset is being allowed), you can simple allow just those.

The basic logic would be that a email only contains `a-z` `0-9` `-` `_` `.` and `@`. If any character outside that set is used, its wrong.

From there, you could specify it more. An email is that set of characters(minus @), than the `@`, then that charset(minus @).
From there, you could add a domain check, eg `\.{2,}$` (must end with dot and at least to letters).
From there...

And that is just the saving part. On display, you need all kinds of tricks to make sure it's not XSS.

---

Or you could just use

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "Not an emailaddress, please try again before submitting!"; 
}
```

Comment: What about `+` in email address? A-Z? 'The basic logic would be that a email only contains a-z 0-9 - _ . and @' isn't true at all.

Comment: An that is a _perfect_ example why that method doesnt work very well! What else did I miss? Very senstative logicx